# How to check whether the user has google maps installed in IOS6?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios6, ios6-maps

I tried searching hard, but to no avail.
In my app, that runs on an IOS6 device also, i have a MAP module that needs a Google map.
Now in IOS6 there can be devices which have iOS6 maps and not Google Maps.
So my Program has to check whether the device has google maps, application .
If not, it will link the user to the appStore to download the GoogleMaps app.
Please guide.. someone.. :(
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"You can use the comgooglemaps URL scheme to launch the Google Maps app for iPhone and perform searches, direction requests, and display map views. When you launch Google Maps your bundle identifier is automatically sent as part of the request."

"Before you present one of these URLs to a user in your app you should first verify that the application is installed. Your app can check that the URL scheme is available with the following code:

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
>       [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]];

"

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme